# How to generate .d.ts file only for javascript files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Since my project is not started with Typescript, so there're some Javascript files yet.

So my idea is to generate a `@types` directory with `.d.ts` files for all the `.jsx?` files (only `.jsx?` files)

My `tsconfig.json` is like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "lib": ["es6"],
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "strict": true,
      "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
      "target": "esnext",
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "paths": {
        "~/*": ["*"]
      },
      "declaration": true,
      "declarationDir": "./types"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "babel.config.js",
      "metro.config.js",
      "jest.config.js",
      "*.ts",
      "*.tsx"
    ],
    "include": [ "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx" ]
  }
```

It's working partially, because it's also creating `.d.ts` file to `.tsx?` files.

How can I generate `.d.ts` files only for `.jsx` and `.js` files?

Answer (score 0):

.dts is self documet file. compaler can't know type of fuinction or type of variable.  If you use for js you must write widt your hands. You can use js doc sysntax. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler